# Get visual studio to "watch" a dist folder

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

I have a gulp task that generates files for me. This script puts the output in a /dist folder and this is then published with the following in the csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="dist\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

I would like to se the contents of this folder while developing, from inside visual studio, so I tried moving the itemgroup up to the main PropertyGroup tag. This gives me a view of the folder in VS as it was on project load. I have to reload the project to get changes. Is there any way to get VS to actually "Watch" the folder and actually change based on the files that are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the ["new" project system](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system) used by .NET Core and ASP.NET Core.
You can use it by changing creating projects using SDK-based project files (.NET Core applications, possibly changing `TargetFramework` to a non-.NET Core string like `net472` or manually hacking GUIDs in the .sln file - see [this documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/3957373f5e5ba4904f03d64099b4d962e6835624/docs/opening-with-new-project-system.md)).

However, if you can use this new project system or not heavily depends on the features you need inside VS. For example, you cannot do this for classic ASP.NET applications, WinForms or WPF applications and you won't have access to designers for EF 6 schemas (.edmx files).

The grand goal is to replace the classic project system with the new one entirely but there is no plan yet for when this is going to happen.

Comment: Aha, unfortunately I am using .net 4.7 and I don't want to hack to much, so it seems like I won't get this  :(